# Bulk clean SVGs from API

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, flutter-exception

I'm building a Flutter app and getting a bunch of svg images from an APi. Some contain the  tags that cause errors to the flutter_svg package. I've searched but only found ways to fix this issue when it's an individual file like use some tools online to clean up the svg.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The following UnimplementedError was thrown in parseSvgElement:

The  element is not implemented in this library.

Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG may not render as intended.

If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes (which are supported), or use a

preprocessing utility such as svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The message tells you about the tool to use: https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner. The GUI seems to be aimed at bulk processing whole folders.